# Alternatives for BKTree

Tags: scala, data-structures, indexing, data-mining

I have a huge list of strings around 150000 of lengths from 16-18. I wanted to search nearest strings from the list. The BKTree data structure slows down as the list grows bigger. I would like to know any better data structure that facilitates this large list and provide nearest string search?

Approaches : I have tried clustering the strings into groups and building tree with the root terms of the clusters. But the speed still not enough as I have huge number of search queries. Suffix trees don't facilitate my need of searching string with say for example maximum distance of 3 or so.

**UPDATE**: The strings are very much similar. The strings are generated from long sequences with n sliding windows length. **So the suffix of one string will be prefix of the another.**

Comment: When you say "nearest strings," what metric are you using to determine nearness?

Comment: I have used the Levenshtein distance metric to determine nearness.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a maximum distance of 3, then you are guaranteed that your strings have an identical run of at least 4 characters.

You can thus hash each segment of length 4 and check whether each is represented in your data set.  Pick whichever exists but has the smallest content, and search a BKTree within that pool.  If your data set itself is not highly self-redundant, this should massively decrease the scope of the search that you need to do.  (You will, in general, need to maintain 15x as many entries in BKTrees as before, so this comes at some maintenance cost.)

I'm not sure whether this initial lookup step will be inexpensive enough to be worth the later improvement; that depends a lot on the structure of the 150k strings, and whether the input strings are likely to be a match to one of them or whether you have a lot of misses.

An alternate approach would be to use a [lernmatrix-style encoding](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-72393-6_100#page-1) of the strings and find the nearest through pattern completion.  Since you'd need a large matrix to store this (probably ~4M elements), I hesitate to recommend this for speed.  All the matrix multiplication is going to take you a few milliseconds.  (You'd have to encode the string in a manner robust to Levenstein edits, e.g. by using deltas on adjacent characters; this would take a non-negligible amount of work to get working.)